# My opengl code should display multiple cubes but only displays a single square

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I am trying to run some code that should render multiple cubes using matrix transformations to translate one cubes coordinates to other locations. However im pretty sure the matricies arent working because all that renders is the original cube without being transformed.

I had a look online at what the problem could be and found that I should initialize my matricies as identity matricies initially which I have already done yet I still see no affect. Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "GLCALL.h"
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <shader.h>
#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "CurrentProject1", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "error not goeerrd\n";

    GLCall(glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST));


    float vertices[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

                         -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

                         -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

                          0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

                         -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

                         -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f };

    glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = { glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f),
                                  glm::vec3(2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f),
                                  glm::vec3(-1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f),
                                  glm::vec3(-3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f),
                                  glm::vec3(2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f),
                                  glm::vec3(-1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f),
                                  glm::vec3(1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f),
                                  glm::vec3(1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f),
                                  glm::vec3(1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f),
                                  glm::vec3(-1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f) };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    GLCall(glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO));
    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &VBO));

    GLCall(glBindVertexArray(VAO));

    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO));
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0));
    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));

    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float))));
    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(1));

    GLCall(unsigned int s_ID = glCreateProgram());
    GLCall(unsigned int vs_ID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
    GLCall(unsigned int fs_ID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));

    const std::string vs_string = "#version 330 core\n"
                                  "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
                                  "uniform mat4 model;\n"
                                  "uniform mat4 view;\n"
                                  "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
                                  "\n"
                                  "void main()\n"
                                  "{\n"
                                  "gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);\n"
                                  "}\n";

    const std::string fs_string = "#version 330 core\n"
                                  "out vec4 color;\n"
                                  "void main()\n"
                                  "{\n"
                                  "color  = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f)\n;"
                                  "}\n";

    const char* vs_char = vs_string.c_str();
    const char* fs_char = fs_string.c_str();
    std::cout << *vs_char;
    GLCall(glShaderSource(vs_ID, 1, &vs_char, NULL));
    GLCall(glShaderSource(fs_ID, 1, &fs_char, NULL));
    GLCall(glCompileShader(vs_ID));

    int result;
    GLCall(glGetShaderiv(vs_ID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result));
    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        GLCall(glGetShaderiv(vs_ID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length));
        char * message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        GLCall(glGetShaderInfoLog(vs_ID, length, &length, message));
        std::cout << "failed to compile vertexing shader" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        GLCall(glDeleteShader(vs_ID));
    }

    GLCall(glCompileShader(fs_ID));

    int result1;
    GLCall(glGetShaderiv(fs_ID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result1));
    if (result1 == GL_FALSE)
    { 
        int length1;
        GLCall(glGetShaderiv(fs_ID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length1));
        char * message = (char*)alloca(length1 * sizeof(char));
        GLCall(glGetShaderInfoLog(fs_ID, length1, &length1, message));
        std::cout << "failed to compile fragmenting shader" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        GLCall(glDeleteShader(fs_ID));
    }

    GLCall((s_ID, vs_ID));
    GLCall(glAttachShader(s_ID, fs_ID));
    GLCall(glLinkProgram(s_ID));
    GLCall(glDeleteShader(vs_ID));
    GLCall(glDeleteShader(fs_ID));
    GLCall(glUseProgram(s_ID));

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);

        GLCall(glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f));
        GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT));

        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));

        const std::string temp1 = "projection";
        const std::string temp2 = "view";
        const std::string temp3 = "model";
        GLCall(glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(s_ID, temp1.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]));
        GLCall(glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(s_ID, temp2.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]));
        GLCall(glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE));

        GLCall(glBindVertexArray(VAO));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);
            float angle = 20.0f * i;
            model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f));
            GLCall(glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(s_ID, temp3.c_str()), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]));
            GLCall(glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36));
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    GLCall(glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO));
    GLCall(glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO));
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    GLCall(glViewport(0, 0, width, height));
}
```

I expect multiple cubes to render in different positions in a perspective projection however instead I see what would be seen if the matrix hadn't been included at all, just a single cube with the coordinates of the original cube. What could be stopping the matricies from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda weird you only have a single `glAttachShader()` call.

I can see multiple cubes with [GLM 0.9.9.2](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/releases/tag/0.9.9.2) and a known-good shader loader:

[image: screenshot of multiple wireframe cubes]

Code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader( obj ) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram( obj ) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader( obj ) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram( obj ) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof( log ), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

const char* vert = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main()
{
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
};
)GLSL";

const char* frag = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
color  = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
};
)GLSL";

void framebuffer_size_callback( GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height );
void processInput( GLFWwindow *window );

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "CurrentProject1", NULL, NULL );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback( window, framebuffer_size_callback );

    if( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
        std::cout << "error not goeerrd\n";

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    float vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    };

    glm::vec3 cubePositions[] =
    {
        glm::vec3( 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f ),
        glm::vec3( 2.0f,  5.0f, -15.0f ),
        glm::vec3( -1.5f, -2.2f, -2.5f ),
        glm::vec3( -3.8f, -2.0f, -12.3f ),
        glm::vec3( 2.4f, -0.4f, -3.5f ),
        glm::vec3( -1.7f,  3.0f, -7.5f ),
        glm::vec3( 1.3f, -2.0f, -2.5f ),
        glm::vec3( 1.5f,  2.0f, -2.5f ),
        glm::vec3( 1.5f,  0.2f, -1.5f ),
        glm::vec3( -1.3f,  1.0f, -1.5f ),
    };

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO );

    glBindVertexArray( VAO );

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof( float ), (void*)0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof( float ), (void*)( 3 * sizeof( float ) ) );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 1 );

    GLuint s_ID = Program::Load( vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL );
    glUseProgram( s_ID );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        processInput( window );

        glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4( 1.0f );
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4( 1.0f );
        projection = glm::perspective( glm::radians( 45.0f ), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f );
        view = glm::translate( view, glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f ) );

        const std::string temp1 = "projection";
        const std::string temp2 = "view";
        const std::string temp3 = "model";
        glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( s_ID, temp1.c_str() ), 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[ 0 ][ 0 ] );
        glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( s_ID, temp2.c_str() ), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[ 0 ][ 0 ] );
        glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );

        glBindVertexArray( VAO );
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4( 1.0f );
            model = glm::translate( model, cubePositions[ i ] );
            float angle = 20.0f * i;
            model = glm::rotate( model, glm::radians( angle ), glm::vec3( 1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f ) );
            glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( s_ID, temp3.c_str() ), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[ 0 ][ 0 ] );
            glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36 );
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &VBO );
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void processInput( GLFWwindow *window )
{
    if( glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) == GLFW_PRESS )
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose( window, true );
}

void framebuffer_size_callback( GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height )
{
    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
}
```